# An adjective for when it is implied that something happens by something else happening

Tags: single-word-requests

Context: Intermediate examinations at a university (non-US/UK) – they can either be in the form of "extra", separate exams to be taken on top of the previous classes, or their results can be simply "implied" or deduced by (say) the average result of the exams taken in previous classes. Looking for an adjective to describe the second scenario. Many thanks!

Example (sort of): My intermediate examinations were [insert adjective], since I passed them without having to take any separate exams but simply by previously having passed the required classes.

Comment: _Academic_. Though you might get some wry looks. _Supererogatory_. Though you'll get some even stranger looks if you use this.

Comment: On re-reading, I think the only thing that makes sense without redefining 'examination' is 'non-existent'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example (sort of): My intermediate examinations were [insert adjective], since I passed them without having to take any separate exams but simply by previously having passed the required classes.

For this specific case, you should use [**exempt**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exempt):

> Free from an obligation or liability imposed on others.
>       *‘they were exempted from paying the tax’*

In your case:

> **I was exempted from** my intermediate examinations, since I had(/have) already passed the required classes beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Redundant would seem to be the suitable word for the example. Redundant: adjective, not or no longer needed or useful; superfluous. Oxford Dic.